# Rotating both hands downwards

Tags: bones, pose-mode

I found my answer some days ago but I forgot how to reproduce it again, my character is in T-pose, and in the final Idle pose both of his hands must be down near his legs. I tried rotating around individual origins, tried R > Y > Y, there was that one option in the menu that allowed me to do what I intend but can't remember which one it was, it worked in pose mode and there was no need for mirroring every time because it happened automatically. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is this that you are looking for, but there is an option to move the mirrored bones if they have names like `arm.L`/`arm.Left` and `arm.R`/`arm.Right`.

Its named *X-Axis mirror* and you can find it in the *Options Tab* when pressing <kbd>T</kbd> while in the *Edit Mode*.